# Javascript module - return JSON object from Ajax request from within module

Tags: javascript, module, callback

I am trying to convert a drag/drop script into a JavaScript module.

NOTE: The problem is not how to return the json object inside the ajax function, the problem is how i return the json object from within the module.

The code works outside the module:

```
    var article_dropzone = document.getElementById("article_dropzone");

    article_dropzone.addEventListener("dragover", dragover);
    article_dropzone.addEventListener("dragleave", dragleave);
    article_dropzone.addEventListener("drop", dragdrop);

    function dragupload(files) {
        ajax("/articleThumbnail.php", false, "POST", false, files[0], function (results) {
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(results);
        });
    }

    function dragover(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    function dragleave(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    function dragdrop(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dragupload(e.dataTransfer.files);
    }
```

But the problem is I need to make a module for reusability and return the JSON object from the ajax call inside the module call.

Module:

```
var drag_upload = (function () {
    var elem_dropzone;
    var elem_page;
    var jsonObj = false;

    var prepare_drag = function (dropzone, page, callback) {

        elem_dropzone = document.getElementById(dropzone);
        elem_page = page;

        elem_dropzone.addEventListener("dragover", dragover);
        elem_dropzone.addEventListener("dragleave", dragleave);
        elem_dropzone.addEventListener("drop", dragdrop);

        callback(jsonObj);
    };

    var dragupload = function (files) {

        ajax(elem_page, false, "POST", false, files[0], function (results) {

            jsonObj = JSON.parse(results);

        });
    };

    var dragover = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };
    var dragleave = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };
    var dragdrop = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dragupload(e.dataTransfer.files);
    };

    return {
        prepare_drag: prepare_drag
    };
})();
```

Calling the module:

```
    drag_upload.prepare_drag(article_dropzone, function (callback) {
        alert(callback);
    });
```

AJAX function

```
    function ajax(url, parameters, method, form = false, files = false, callback = false) {
        var ajax_http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var ajax_parameters;

        ajax_http.open(method, url, true);
        if (form === false && files === false) {
            ajax_parameters = parameters;
            ajax_http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        } else {
            ajax_parameters = form ? new FormData(form) : new FormData();

            if (files) {
                if (files.length == null) {
                    ajax_parameters.append("file", files);
                } else {
                    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        ajax_parameters.append("file[]", files[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ajax_http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajax_http.readyState === 4 && ajax_http.status === 200) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(ajax_http.responseText);
                } else {
                    return ajax_http.responseText;
                }
            }
        };
        ajax_http.send(ajax_parameters ? ajax_parameters : null);
    }
```

I tried a few different things, the latest is making a callback function, but obviously, it will return false because it will run immediately as the module is called and therefore have no JSON object attached.

Does anyone have a tip or anything that can help me solve this?

**Managed to find a way to do this, I just find it a bit messy.**

Calling the module:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
    var article_dropzone = "article_dropzone";
    var pag_test = "/articleThumbnail.php";


    drag_upload.prepare_drag(article_dropzone, pag_test);
    document.getElementById(article_dropzone).addEventListener("drop", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var file = e.dataTransfer.files;
        drag_upload.dragupload(file, function (callback) {
            console.log(callback);
        });
    });

});
```

The module:

```
var drag_upload = (function () {
    var elem_dropzone;
    var drp_files;
    var drp_page;

    var prepare_drag = function (dropzone, page) {

        elem_dropzone = document.getElementById(dropzone);
        drp_page = page;

        elem_dropzone.addEventListener("dragover", dragover);
        elem_dropzone.addEventListener("dragleave", dragleave);
    };

    var dragupload = function (file, callback) {
        ajax(drp_page, false, "POST", false, file[0], function (results) {
            callback(JSON.parse(results));
        });
    };

    var dragover = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };
    var dragleave = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    return {
        prepare_drag: prepare_drag, 
        dragupload: dragupload

    };
})();
```

Doing it the way above seems to me like i don't really need the module except if i want dragover/dragleave options, and i find it a bit more messy, is there not a smarter way of doing it?